# I want to know the specific reason why we have take those 256,.. numbers in the conversion below

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Projected code is used to convert a date into integer and vice-versa. I want to know the reason why here we have used this specific hexadecimal codes and the number series to get back the date from int. If there is an article about this code sample it would also help me understand this code actually.

I have tried online Hex to Decimal conversion for this codes and found its a 256^1,256^2... even though trying not able to find the exact reason.

```
declare @dDate date = '2017-10-12'
declare @iDate int = 0

select @iDate = ( (datepart(year,@dDate)*65536 | datepart(month,@dDate)*256 | datepart(dd,@dDate)))

select (@iDate&0xfff0000)/65536  --year
select (@iDate&0xff00)/256   --Month
select (@iDate&0xff)         --Date
```

Comment: These are some important dates which cannot be revealed so these needs to b encrypted. And this is the encryption format. If you don't have an answer its ok. I understand.

Answer (score 1):

& is an operator doing bitwise AND.  "|" is bitwise OR.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  Also see [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1218/sql-server-bitwise-operators-to-store-multiple-values-in-one-column/) for an explanation on using bitwise AND/OR to store multiple number values in a single number column.
This part:

```
@iDate&0xfff0000
```

will "mask", or eliminate/replace-with-zeros, the portion of iDate that isn't from 256^2.  Then you divide by 65536 -- which is simply reversing the original math of multiplying the year by 65536.

If the concept of bitwise AND is foreign, I'll give an example that DOESN'T WORK in decimal.  Bitwise AND converts the whole thing to binary and then masks things (like IP subnetting, if you're familiar with that).

Anyway, consider a decimal number 20171012.  If such a thing as a decimal-wise AND existed, it could look like `20171012&11110000`.  The "1" places are "keepers" and the "0" places are "throw-aways".  If you stack them vertically, the result is to keep the values with a "1" beneath them and replace the values with a "0" beneath them with a "0".

```
number       20171012
dec-wise AND 11110000
result       20170000
```

now the result isn't 2017, so you'd have to divide by 10000 to get 2017.
For `20171012&1100` you have to use implied leading zeros:

```
number       20171012
dec-wise AND 00001100
result           1000
```

I probably would have converted to int by adding the year*10000 and month * 100 and day.  Reverting back I would use a combination of integer division and MOD.  But I think the bitwise AND is perhaps a bit more elegant (particularly for getting the month).

Based on your comment, I will include how I have converted dates to int and reverted back:

```
declare @dDate date = '2017-10-12'
declare @iDate int

set @iDate = year(@dDate) * 10000 + month(@dDate) * 100 + day(@dDate)

select @iDate

select 'year', @iDate/10000 -- basic integer division provides the year
select 'month', (@iDate % 10000)/100 -- combine modulo and integer division to get the month
select 'day', @iDate % 100  -- basic modulo arithmetic provides the day
```

returns:

```
20171012
year    2017
month     10
day       12
```

Comment: number       20171012
dec-wise AND 11110000
result       20170000

Comment: Wat if conversion is like 2017 | 10 | 12

Comment: Division and doing modulus is not as efficient as doing bitwise `AND` and `OR`

Comment: Performance would be an interesting thing to test.  Both methods include integer division for year and month.  2 modulo operations vs. 3 bitwise and operations.  I just wonder how significant it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit manipulation.

**Bit Shifting**

Decimal 3 = Binary 11

If we do a left shift (`<<`) `4 bits` in `3` it will become `48` which is equal to binary `110000` <- `4` zero bits added due to left shift

But since we don't have bit shifting operators in T-SQL therefore we can do the math.

Left Shifting of `n` bits in number `x` = `x * 2^n`

Therefore, multiple a number with 256 is actually left shift 8 bits from that number (2^8 = 256).

Later on when you do bitwise `OR` between 2 numbers they actually "concatenate" the bits up.

For example, you need to concatenate 2 binary numbers, (3) 11 and (2) 10, the resultant number should be 1110 = 14

So first we'll do 2 left shift in 3 = 3 * 2^2 = 12 and then we will do bitwise `OR` this number with the next number

```
    12 = 1100
     2 = 0010
OR 
---------------
    14 = 1110
```

Your example is actually saving the whole date in an integer variable which is actually efficient way of saving a date.

Comment: It's interesting to me that the original code chose 65536 and 256.  I think 64 and 1024 would have been sufficient.  I guess the masks are harder to comprehend, though.